# Fixed javascript ID using autoload_scripts from bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

**Goal:**

Daily update plots and save them as java script functions using Bokeh's autoload_scripts. Have a html webpage that shows the plots. Do not have to change the html code each day.

**Problem:**

Following the example here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#bokeh-applications

I am able to see the plot on my webpage. But each time I call autoload_scripts() it generates a new id, which I must update in the html file so it can load the new java script.

**Question:**

Is there a way to have a fixed id? Or is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance, new to Bokeh and javascript, so apologize if not using the right tool here.

Answer (score 1):

The original motivation behind `autoload_static` was to have a function that could be used when generating dynamic web pages, e.g. a Flask endpoint. Being able to have a fixed ID seems like a reasonable use-case, it's just not one that ever occurred to us, so it's not implemented. I'd encourage you to file a [GitHub feature request](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to have support for fixed IDs added.

In the mean time, the best suggestion I can offer is to copy the code from `autoload_static` and add a line that sets `render_items[0]['elementid']` to use a hard-coded ID of your choosing. It's not a large function, it is located here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/embed/standalone.py#L50-L100

The new section of code would look something like:

```
with _ModelInDocument([model]):
        (docs_json, render_items) = standalone_docs_json_and_render_items([model])

    render_items[0]['elementid'] = "MY FIXED ID"
    bundle = bundle_all_models()
```